# Ошибка в поиске по странице - нет вывода данных

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

При попытке вывода ссылок со страницы программа не осуществляется вывод данных:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen ('https://www.russianrealty.ru/goroda-i-regiony/')
bsj = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = bsj.find("ul",{'class':'list-col-count'}).find_all("li",{"href":re.compile("[^A-Z]*")})
for i in x:
    print(i.attrs["href"])
```

Comment: `{"href":re.compile("[^A-Z]*")}` вы используете для того, чтобы найти только те ссылки, у которых есть атрибут `href`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь найти все `<li>` с атрибутом `href`, но нужно искать `<a>`.

Попробуйте так:

```
x = bsj.find("ul",{'class':'list-col-count'}).find_all("a",{"href":re.compile("[^A-Z]*")})
```

Или короче:

```
x = bsj.find("ul",{'class':'list-col-count'}).find_all("a", href=True)
```

Или с помощью CSS селекторов:

```
x = bsj.select('.list-col-count > li > a[href]')
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо ))